# Autentificar usuarios

Tags: laravel

Veran, estoy intentando hacer un sistema de autentificación de usuarios con Laravel.
Para ello, se supone que debo escribir en CMD este codigo: `php artisan make:auth` y eso hara que me aparezca lo siguiente:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero aunque me sale un mensaje de confirmación (`Authentication scaffolding generated successfully`), no me aparece la imagen. ¿Donde voy para verla?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pones

```
php artisan serve
```

y ahí te dice cómo ver tu pantalla.

Comment: Pues ha funcionado. Eso si, más bien es "php artisan serve".

Answer (score 1):

El comando `php artisan make:auth` te crea modelo, controlador y ruta para la autentificación y registro de usuarios.

Y el comando `php artisan serve` pone en marcha el servidor.

Para que Laravel (Laravel es un framework de código abierto para desarrollar aplicaciones y servicios web con PHP ), funcione correctamente el servidor siempre debe estar en marcha, es obvio pero a veces nos olvidamos de lo fácil.